# executemany command very slow on pg8000 for postgres on Azure

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2, pg8000

I am using pg8000 to update the data in my postgres database on Azure from a csv file but the execution is painfully slow,

this is my code

```
command = "INSERT INTO public.tempcumulativesales (combined, cumulative_sales) VALUES (%s, %s)"
with open('./UpdateDatabaseFiles/rows1.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file)
    data = list(csv.reader(file))
    cursor.executemany(command, data)
```

does anyone know how I can improve the speed?

the csv file has 12,000 + entries

Comment: Use COPY.  https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#copy-from-and-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

12000 entries can be large if each entry is. Without more info on the structure of the table, the existence of constraint or indexes, we cannot give a definitive answer.

Possible improvements:

- do not wait to have read evertything to start inserting into the table - said differently directly use the reader iterator:

  ```
  data = csv.reader(file)
  ```
- if 12000 is too large and shorter commits could be more efficient (by reducing the rollback segment), use chunks:

  ```
    def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # from itertools recipes
        # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    ...
    chunksize = 1024    # experiment to find best one
    for chunk in grouper(data, chunksize):
        cursor.executemany(command,filter(lambda x: x is not None, i))
        db_con.commit()
  ```